# Бесплатное обслуживание сайта. Существует ли такая услуга?

Tags: веб-сайт

Пожалуйста, не считайте мой такой вопрос сразу поиском "халявы". Я не совсем по этому поводу, всё объясню ниже.

Изучил тему в поисковых системах но не нашёл ничего толкового по данному вопросу, возможно потому что такой услуги и не существует, поскольку действительно если подумать зачем кому то делать это бесплатно, возможно и у Вас мой вопрос о бесплатном обслуживании сайта вызвал недоумевание, но пожалуйста выслушайте, я сейчас всё объясню.

На самом деле я уже не первый раз задумываюсь о услуге бесплатного обслуживания и пытаюсь найти что то подобное в Интернет, но пока чего то конкретного не увидел. Вот смотрите как я считаю: с чем связана такая необходимость и почему обслуживающей стороне это так же может быть выгодно.

Я за 2 с половиной года открыл второй Интернет магазин. Я сам экономист по образованию, и хостинги, css, CMS Joomla(хотя и есть планы перейти на Bitrix) - всё это по началу было тяжело, да и сейчас. Не сказать что Интернет магазин приносит мне большие деньги, но он всё таки приносит, при этом приносит он их бывает, увы, не каждый месяц, а поскольку проблемы возникают то с хостингом, то очень нужно какой то блок поправить и тяжело и долго, а бывает ещё и после самостоятельно потраченного времени всё без результатов и всё равно приходится или обращаться в компанию с которая создавала, или если нужно экономность то найти фрилансера, а если его искать то нужно сделать бэкап(на случай если он что то сломает, такие случаи у меня были, хотя я это понимаю ведь деньги не большие и возможно попадают не опытные новички), на у время на поиски самого флилансера. Возможно Вы подумаете, что мешает найти на постоянного фрилансера и сотрудничать с ним? Да пробовал уже, были 3 хороших, хотя один есть и сейчас но ценники поднялись, хотя бывает его всё равно прошу. Не знаю как у других, но у меня ситуация такая, что всё рано фрилансеры на время, потому что кто то просит потом больше денег, а кто то говорит что взял более интересный(или большой проект) за который и платят больше и не может отвлекаться на сторонние дела. И я это понимаю. Так что работа с фрилансером не за дорого(опять же по моей практике) это ещё и трата времени на поиски этого всякого фрилансера.

Я подумал вот что. Но ведь по сути тема с бесплатным(а вернее возможно условно бесплатным, если конкретно мой случай рассматривать, ведь я что то и за деньги готов делать) вполне может быть экономически выгодна для стороны обслуживающей. Ведь я понимаю если действительно что то сложное или занимающее время, то за трату времени программиста нужно платить. А я иногда могу и сайт заказать или разработать какой то модуль для него. И понятно что я эти деньги отдам уже человеку с которым есть договорённость, при этом я готов ждать когда он освободится, то есть мне бывает не прямо срочно нужно.

Тут же думаю важно написать - лично я не подразумеваю например бесплатный хостинг, потому что заплатить 300 рублей за хостинг и домен ну это то нормально.

Дело именно в том, что получается для моей уверенности на случай когда на сайте что то ломается(что для программистов быстро и по мелочам, а для меня то нет), у меня бы был кто то кто сможет достаточно оперативно решить и если нужно за разумные деньги. Например была у меня ситуация закончился SSL, пробовал сам написал хостинг-провайдер мне написал как поправить, но я не справился по инструкции, хотя программист который помогал с установкой нового сертификата, пояснил что хостинг всё нормально мне написал и именно это по идее он и сделал. При этом я заплатил 3000 рублей студии за минимальный пакет услуг по обслуживанию за месяц - в чём я и вижу основную проблему. То есть для меня 3000 рублей именно накладно платить, потому что простой бывает. А поскольку я тогда на эту проблему с сертификатом потратил 4 дня у меня сорвался нормальный заказ за 12 тысяч рублей, человек заказавший посчитал меня проблемным или сомнительным, хотя он мне так и не сказал, но я сам так предполагаю, потому что в телефонном разговоре потом обмолвился, что там заходил  в личный кабинет а там сайт ошибку безопасности выдавал.

Может я конечно в этом вопросе чего то не понимаю или не учитываю, просветите пожалуйста. Приоритетнее, конечно, если такая услуга у кого есть, то организацию, потому что стабильности бы хотелось. И очень важно чтобы можно было по телефону позвонить. Уважаемые! Я всё понимаю: месседжеры, skype, e-mail - всё это замечательно и порой очень даже удобно, при этом поймите, владельцу сайта бывает сложно сформулировать, что у него SSL закончился, хотелось бы просто позвонить по телефону и условно сказать: Иван, я захожу на сайт в браузере виду то-то и то-то, можешь мне для начала сказать что это за ситуация, что мне с ней делать и если делать будешь ты то во сколько обойдётся по деньгам и времени.

Comment: `Bitrix` ... `То есть для меня 3000 рублей именно накладно платить` ... `Bitrix` обойдется раз в 1000 дороже. Да и разработчики его не любят. Сам как то смотрел - это просто ... слов нет. `Ведь я понимаю если действительно что то сложное или занимающее время, то за трату времени программиста нужно платить. ` 1К евро  месяц минимум.

Comment: Я понимаю что Bitrix это лицензия и что разработка дороже. А почему Вы считаете что разработчики его не любят? С программистами которыми я общался - они говорят что в Bitrix просто нужно вникнуть, а далее у него есть преимущества как для разработчика так и для пользователя. У Вас какая то другая информаия? А по поводу оплаты 3000 в месяц за обслуживание, так бывают ещё и ситуации что несколько месяцев сайт в простое а платить получается нужно, при этом если он не будет работать заказ можно пропустить. Поэтому и спрашиваю вот как бы этот момент решить...

Comment: Почему не любят Битрикс? Тут недавно статья на Хабре проскакивала. Жаль, что в закладки не кинул, никак найти не могу... Выжимка из статьи: `Код Битрикс-а "какакшка", шаг влево/вправо от стандартной конфигурации - "расстрел"`

Comment: Мало что могу прокомментировать по этому поводу. Знаю что мне фрилансеры говорили с которыми доводилось работать(из тех ребят у которых никаких сложностей не возникало и они всё быстро делали), они говорят кто CMS знает можно Joomla а можно и Bitrix и без разницы. Кто знаком с разработкой они знают где у них проблемы. Знаю что битрикс очень нужен если есть 1с(у меня пока без неё).И даже говорили что на Bitrix магазины например быстрее делать,а стоит дороже потому что это политика самого Bitrix.Кто то даже говори что за это Bitrix и любят.Я пока не пробовал на своих сайтах,только в лаборатории

Comment: Просто почитайте [коментарии разработчиков](https://habr.com/ru/post/517114/)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопрос не по теме.

Comment: eanmos, если Вас это не затруднит поясните пожалуйста, что я сделал не верно. Тема про обслуживание сайтов, размещена в теге сайты. Тематика вопрос IT. Существуют же например темы на примере: "кто и что думает про бесплатный хостинг" и обсуждается же на подобных ресурсах. Обслуживание это услуга как и хостинг. К тому же я написал, что не однократно думал про возможное существование такой услуги, так как обслуживающей стороне тоже это может быть выгодно. Хочу для себя определиться уже по вопросу, потому что интересно(возможно и другим), почему не нашёл такого при том что есть выгоды.

Answer (score 0):

В условиях кризиса все хотят сэкономить, и это логично :)

Я обслуживаю пару сайтов на Joomla:

- одной управляющей компании (ЖКХ) за 15 тыс руб (хостинг, домен + доработки и помощь в администрировании). Они, правда, давно уже ничего не делают сами и не просят ничего допиливать.
- одному детскому дому за 6 тыс руб (аналогично). Им, наоборот, часто приходится помогать - примерно раз в месяц что-нибудь сделать не сложное.

С SSL вообще можно сэкономить с помощью LetsEncrypt, настроив его автоматическое обновление.

Бесплатно, было дело, обслуживал сайты. Это были социальные проекты, которые потом завершили свой жизненный цикл.